# Which is better: create entity classes then generate table Or create table firstly then generate entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I watched some online JPA tutorials. All the tutors create JAVA entity classes then use hibernate to create tables. Why don't create tables firstly then generate classes using JPA tools->generate classes from tables. For example, it will be a headache to write a many-to-many class using JAVA,

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Role.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM Role r")
public class Role implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  private String role;

  //bi-directional many-to-many association to User
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
    name="user_role"
    , joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
        }
    , inverseJoinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
        }
    )
  private List<User> users;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to create entity classes first.After that when we create object for session factory the tables ll be created automatically.

If we create tables first then we may miss to add the things like relation ships...